# Getting partial result of XmlHttpRequest freezes the browser in IE 11

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest

I have a script that reads data from XmlHttpRequest and once in a while calls specified callback for the data it has read. It is done so users do not have to download the whole file to start viewing it.

So after sending the request I added handler for readystatechange event which, simplified, looks like this:

```
request.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (request.readyState !== 3 && request.readyState !== 4 || request.status !== 200) {
        return;
    }

    var responseText = request.responseText;
    if (responseText.length === 0) {
        return;
    }

    if (stream.offset + responseText.length > stream.processed) {
        var chunk = responseText.substring(stream.processed - stream.offset);
        stream.processed += chunk.length;
        stream.callback(chunk);
    }
};
```

It works fine in Chrome 36 and Firefox 31, but in IE 11 the page become frozen for a minute.

So I ran the profiler and here the first line was
[image: profiler result]

So my question is: why it takes so much time to access the responseText and what can I do about it?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I've run into this same problem as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, I did't. I just adjusted setting to call callback less often in IE.